# I have problem when i import Django-Markdownx

Tags: python, django, import, django-markdownx

i have problem when i import markdownx.
i installed Markdownx for Django, and add in url.
and i want to in models.py, but it has problem.
problem is..
**(Import 'markdownx.models' could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) [3, 6])**

And my code

> Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
    'single_pages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'crispy_forms',
    'markdownx',
]
```

> project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
    path('', include('single_pages.urls')),
]
```

> blog/models.py

```
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hook_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = MarkdownxField()
```

[when i import this line, it has problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvDlb.png)

Comment: Regardless of the VSCode error, does the code actually run?

Comment: no, i can't run the code..  I wanna know why can't i import markdownx.models ~~. i have install, add url, but it doesn't work.

Comment: please, check image what i attached in last line

Comment: No, what I mean is, can you run `django-admin runserver` and not get errors? If you do get errors, please edit your question and put them into your post as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Oh, i solve this problem! I rebooted VSCode and it worked fine. I keep having a problem with the 'markdownx.models' line, but it has been fixed. Thanks for the comment!